# How to start rails server with mina?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using mina to deploy a rails application to my server. Everything works, but I also want to be able to automatically start the rails server on deploy. Inside of :launch I run the rails s command, but I get an error on deploy that says  'rails: command not found !     ERROR: Deploy failed.'

```
on :launch do
  in_path(fetch(:current_path)) do
    command %{mkdir -p tmp/}
    command %{touch tmp/restart.txt}
    command %{rails s -p myport -b myserver -e production -d}
    end
end
```

how can I get mina to start the server automatically?

Comment: do you have in a deploy script header require 'mina/rails'

Answer (score 0):

Did you install rails on your server?
Did you setup ruby with rvm or rbenv? After proper installation you need to
follow this guide: https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md. Then run the below command

```
mina setup
```

Inside:`on :launch do
      in_path(fetch(:current_path)) do
        invoke :'puma:start'
      end
    end`

It will automatically start your app.